# Custom Collection in Dart?

Tags: dart

I'm trying to figure out how I can create a custom collection of custom objects in Dart and having List as an abstract class I see no other way than to 'have' a List in my custom collection:

```dart
class MenuItemCollection {

  List<MenuItem> _items;

  MenuItemCollection() {
    _items = new List<MenuItem>();
  }

  List<MenuItem> get items => _items;
}
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no way to extend List yet. Here is the bug to star to vote for this feature: http://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=2600

Comment: Seth, does that mean not being able to extend List is considered a bug? I thought this was by design?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like :

```dart
class MenuItemCollection implements List<MenuItem> {
  final _list = new List<MenuItem>();
  MenuItemCollection();

  noSuchMethod(InvocationMirror invocation) => invocation.invokeOn(_list);
}
```

Comment: You could also use noSuchMethod to catch everything and forward to the encapsulated list :) Something like class EdgeList {
  final list = new ArrayList<Edge>();

  noSuchMethod(mirror) => mirror.invokeOn(list);
}

Comment: Did you test it? I didn't try it :)

Comment: I have faith in you ;) ... and I also tested it after your comment :)

Comment: I've changed one line to:
final List<MenuItem> _list = new List<MenuItem>();
and tested in my project, works.
Do I remember correctly that currently mirrors only works in the VM?

Comment: My original question was if there is a better solution than the one I posted. Is your solution better or just an alternative?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

> List< E>
>
> Queue< E>
>
> Set< E>

or simply an array `E[]`

The best approach is to use the Collection framework (so the first 3 options). But if you want you can even make a recursive array.